# How to avoid the problem of CORS in Angular and Spring boot project?

Tags: angular, spring

I've actually crate an angular service  to get data from the server which running on 'localhost:8080/' (endpoint /user) .
But when I serve the angular project on 'localhost:4200' it made this Error :Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:8080/user' from origin ..

I tried to solve this problem by adding @CrossOrigin(origins = "*") in the controller
and I add a proxy.conf.json in the angular project like I found here : 'https://angular.io/guide/build' But the problem persist .

this is the angular service :

```
  @Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RestService {
  api = 'localhost:8080/user'
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  getUsers(): Observable<String> {
    return this.http.get<String>(this.api);
  }
}
```

this is my proxy.conf.json :

```
{
    "/*": {
        "target": "http://localhost:8080",
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "debug"
    }
}
```

this is the conf in  angular.json :

```
"serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "crud:build",
            "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
          }
```

and this is the spring boot controller :

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")

public class userController {
    @GetMapping("/user")
    public String getuser(){
        return "the user name is bilel" ;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know if `"/*"` is supported. But it is for your interest to prefix all the backend calls with `/api` or `/backend`, then you could use `/api` in your proxy conf (it will make things easier for your Apache/Nginx conf later). Also, you must chose, either you handle this on frontend side (with the proxy, as you did) or from the backend side, with the `@CrossOrigin` but not both. IMHO, `@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")` is a very bad idea (absolute anti-pattern). Also, can you try to add `changeOrigin:true` in your proxy conf ?

Comment: thank you very much for this advice  I try "/* " and I found that is not supported : 
'Error: [HPM] Invalid context. Expecting something like: "/api" '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would not want to tell your Angular service about the target server and its port, it's against the use of the proxy conf.

Call something like a generic api/ root endpoint and map it :

```js
export class RestService {
  api = '/api/user'
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  getUsers(): Observable<String> {
    return this.http.get<String>(this.api);
  }
}
```

And the proxy like that :

```json
{
    "/api": {
        "target": "http://localhost:8080",
        "secure": false
    }
}
```

Comment: for this to work you need to add a path rewrite to the configuration of the proxy so that the additional api in the url is deleted before the request is sent to the backend

Comment: Well, it depends of course on the endpoints you declared in your Spring controllers, and /api is merely a convention, you're right :)

Comment: thank you very much I resolve  this problem , but  unfortunately  I have another  Unexpected token h in JSON at position 1 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHtt…, text: 'the user name is bilel'  and I m trying to solve it .. thanks

Answer (score 3):

To build onto @Alain Boudard's answer, you need to add a path rewrite:

```
export class RestService {
  baseUrl = 'api/user'

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getUsers(): Observable<string> {
    return this.http.get<string>(this.baseUrl);
  }
}
```

and the in the proxy.conf.json file, don't forget the pathRewrite so that 'api' is deleted from the URL before the call is made to the backend:

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/api": ""
    }
  }
}
```

PS: By the way, you will very rarely need to use type String, instead use the primitive string (lowercase s): https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html

Comment: I wanted to thank you for the  advice of the string using , but I didn't understand the utility of the pathRewrite

Comment: if you don't use the pathRewrite the url you are trying to reach on the backend is http://localhost:8080/api/user, with the pathRewrite, you do not need to change the implementation of your backend, it will call the backend on the http://localhost:8080/user url just like in your original question